Как применить функцию к каждому аргументу макроса?
Хочу получить такое поведение, чтобы каждый аргумент макроса был заключен в некоторый код. Например, напечатать каждый аргумент:
#define print_all(...) /* magic */

print_all(1, 2, "123"); // calls std::cout << 1; std::cout << 2; std::cout << "123";


Вот тут https://habr.com/ru/articles/553636/ много всего рассказано о макросах. Но, (хотя я сам люблю их использовать) я бы не советовал делать некую "систему программирования" на макросах. Помните, что создатели языка всегда рассматривали макросы как текстовую подстановку. Следуйте KISS-принципу, иначе  через полгода сами  уже не поймете, как именно "вот эта штука" работает.

Вдогонку к предыдущему комментарию — особенно при работе с С++! Ну с С еще как-то можно понять любовь к макросам, но с С++?...

да не в любви дело; многие системы до сих пор на макросах (см. тестовые фреймворки, логирование и т.п. где нужны подстановки на месте вызова)

Допускаю. Но зачем плодить новые? :)

Уф, поехали. Как обычно, я расчитываю что пользователи MSVC пользуются /std:c++latest /Zc:preprocessor (или 20 вместо latest) (работать со старым препроцессором - последнее дело).
Есть три варианта:

Ровно как вы хотите, через макрос. Для этого нужно нагенерировать N однотипных макросов, где N - максимальное число аргументов. Это нужно, поскольку рекурсия в макросах не работает. (Вроде умельцы как-то делают меньше макросов чем N (логарифм от N?), но я бы туда не углублялся.)
#define LOOP(m, d, ...) __VA_OPT__(LOOP_0(m, d, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOOP_0(m, d, x, ...) m(d, x) __VA_OPT__(LOOP_1(m, d, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOOP_1(m, d, x, ...) m(d, x) __VA_OPT__(LOOP_2(m, d, __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOOP_2(m, d, x, ...) m(d, x) __VA_OPT__(LOOP_3(m, d, __VA_ARGS__))

// ---

#define STEP(d, x) (d,x)

LOOP(STEP, 42) // ничего
LOOP(STEP, 42, 1) // (42,1)
LOOP(STEP, 42, 1,2) // (42,1)(42,2)
LOOP(STEP, 42, 1,2,3) // (42,1)(42,2)(42,3)

Обратите внимание на аргумент d - чтобы проносить дополнительную информацию в цикл снаружи цикла, если она там нужна (или можно оставить пустым).
Этот вариант очень удачно игнорирует запятую после последнего аргумента.

Через макрос, но с другим синтаксисом: FOO((1)(2)(3)). Это позволяет не генерировать N однотипных макросов.
Тут есть два подвида:

Простой - который не позволяет проносить информацию снаружи в тело цикла (как аргумент d выше), зато пишется просто. (И как следствие, этот вариант нельзя один раз абстрагировать в "макрос цикла" как в примере выше, и портянку нужно писать заново для каждого отдельного вида цикла.)
#define END(...) END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END

#define BODY(...) std::cout << __VA_ARGS__;

#define LOOP_A(...) BODY(__VA_ARGS__) LOOP_B
#define LOOP_B(...) BODY(__VA_ARGS__) LOOP_A
#define LOOP_A_END
#define LOOP_B_END

#define LOOP(...) END(LOOP_A __VA_ARGS__)

LOOP() // Ничего
LOOP((1)(2)(3)) // std::cout << 1; std::cout << 2; std::cout << 3;

Этот фокус с двумя макросами, вызывающими друг друга, рекурсией не считается, и поэтому работает для любого размера списка (но для синтаксиса (1) это не работает).

Сложный - который позволяет проносить информацию в тело цикла. Через преобразование (a)(b)(c) сначала к последовательности вида a)b)c). Это откровенно сложно (поэтому полный код не привожу), но достаточно написать один раз.
Я это подглядел кое у кого, и оформил в виде библиотеки: https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for

Еще, конечно, можно поступить как в пункте (1) и нагенерировать себе N макросов, но непонятно зачем так делать, когда есть предыдущий вариант.



Ну и третий способ - использовать шаблон вместо макроса, как предложили в соседнем ответе. Но там предложили не самый лучший способ это делать: во-первых рекурсия не нужна, а во-вторых (особенно при рекурсии!) аргументы лучше передавать по ссылке. (уже починили)
В общем виде так:
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...P>
void foo(P &&... params)
{
    (void(std::cout << std::forward<P>(params) << '\n'), ...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(1,2,"foo"); // 1 2 foo
}

Или если аргументы read-only, то проще и лучше так:
template <typename ...P>
void foo(const P &... params)
{
    (void(std::cout << params << '\n'), ...);
}




В C++ это можно сделать без макросов:
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(int x) : x(x) { std::cout << "cons a\n"; }
    A(const A& a) : x(a.x) { std::cout << "copy cons a\n"; }
    int x;
};

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const A &a) {
    return os << a.x;
}

void print_all() {}

template<typename Type, typename... Types>
void print_all(Type&& arg, Types&&... args) {
    std::cout << std::forward<Type>(arg);
    print_all(std::forward<Types>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    A a(42);
    print_all(1, 2, "123", a);
}


Конструкторы копирования не вызываются и рекурсии нет:

$ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.cpp 

$ ./a.out
cons a
1212342


    ...
    movl    $.LC0, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    movl    $1, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movl    $2, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movl    $3, %edx
    movl    $.LC1, %esi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
    leaq    4(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
    call    _ZlsRSoRK1A
    ...


Ага, а ещё можно просто std::print написать в C++ 1 строкой) Но надо в макросах, которые до сих пор необходимы в некоторых местах
